# how to run process from batch script

Tags: linux, bash, kill, rsyslog

I have simple **batch** script in **linux debian** - Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 - that stop process then deletes log files and start the process again :

```
#!/bin/bash
killall -KILL rsyslogd
sleep 5s
rm /var/log/syslog
rm /var/log/messages
rm /var/log/kern.log
sleep 3s
rsyslogd
exit
```

The process name is *rsyslogd*. I have to close it before deleting the log files, for linux to empty the space from disk.

I see that *killall -KILL* closes the process by its name, but what is the opposite - the run command?
Calling it by its name without any command seems to not work. I will be glad for any tips, thank you.

Comment: Is this intended to avoid wasting space with those logs? If so, you could rotate them with [`logrotate`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate).

Comment: I have read some about logrotate, but I wanna to delete them, not to save them. And is it kills process and starts it again? Bc when the process that saves logs is not killed, the space will be still reserved even after delete the files.

Comment: `logrotate` has a bunch of options that should help you handle the logs. Not only can it save older files, but it can remove them. Check the man page for details on how to configure it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian uses `systemd` to manage processes. You should, therefore, use the systemd's commands to stop and start `rsyslogd`.

```
systemctl stop rsyslog
```

and

```
systemctl start rsyslog
```

If you are using *really* old versions of Debian (so old that you should upgrade), it may be possible that sys V is still used. In that case, there is a file under `/etc/init.d` which is called `rc.rsyslog` or something comparable (use `ls /etc/init.d` to find the exact name). In that case, it would be

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rc.rsyslog stop
```

and

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rc.rsyslog start
```

Or it may be, that your `systemd`-package may be broken. In that case, the package can be re-installed:

```
apt-get --reinstall install systemd
```

Comment: Your idea about path to file with "stop" and "start" options is accurate, and works fine. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

To start rsyslogd:

```
 systemctl start rsyslog
```

To stop it:

```
 systemctl stop rsyslog
```

If you want to do both, use

```
 systemctl restart rsyslog
```

Comment: this is not working - ./skrypt1.sh: line 8: systemctl: command not found

Comment: What version of Debian do you use?

Comment: Debian GNU/Linux 6.0

Comment: @Renver - Why on earth would you use **that**? It's been out of support for over 5 years...